# Apache FOP - PDF creation russian text

Tags: java, apache, pdf, apache-fop

I have a small Java application that creates (besides other stuff) a PDF file using Apache's FOP 1.0.
Everything works fine when using latin letters. But it doesn't when there are others - e.g. cyrillic.

I don't think, it is the default problem of missing fonts, since the bookmarks within the PDF file are alright (unfortunately I can't add pics to this post).

Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

in your f:block you need to specify the font you want to use

```
    <fo:block font-family="MS Mincho" font-size="12pt" font-weight="normal" space-after="5mm" background-color="#8BAF3F" color="white">
```

Of course the font should be available as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints.

I've had set the font-family to 'Verdana', which may or may not have cyrillic letters.
Additionally I set the font-family in 'simple-page-master', so all pages using this master should be using this font.

On basis of your hints I changed the font-family to 'Arial'.
I also set the font-family in one block explicitly, just for a simple test.
I tried even a change of the system language to russian.
Unfortunately nothing worked. The changes of the font-family can be seen each and every time (Arial, Courier, Times, MS Mincho, MAC C Times) on the changed style, but there are always '#' shown.

And, most confusing, the bookmarks are alright...